# Gammu cannot contact device after sending first sms

Tags: gammu

I have installed `gammu 1.33.0-3` and `gammu-smsd 1.33.0-3`. When starting gammu and injecting some message into the SQL-Queue, the message is being sent. However, after the first sms nothing works anymore and I need to `kill -9` gammu in order to be able to start it again.

Please see the information below. Would be great if someone is able to help.

```
root@sms ~ $ gammu identify 
Device               : /dev/ttyUSB0
Manufacturer         : Huawei
Model                : unknown (K3765)
Firmware             : 11.126.03.06.00
IMEI                 : 358...
SIM IMSI             : 262...
```

When sending the first sms, everything works fine, but `gammu-smsd` seems to break directly afterwards.

strace shows the following odd behavior of `gammu-smsd` after sending the first sms. It seems like `gammu-smsd` is stuck doing something with `/etc/localtime`. The screen gets pretty much spammed with those entries.

```
nanosleep({1, 0}, 0x7fffbacc4fa0)       = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
nanosleep({1, 0}, 0x7fffbacc4fa0)       = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
nanosleep({1, 0}, 0x7fffbacc4fa0)       = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
nanosleep({1, 0}, 0x7fffbacc4fa0)       = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
[...] repeats for hundreds of times..
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 357) = 357
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
write(4, "-\1\0\0\3SELECT `ID`, `InsertIntoDB`"..., 305) = 305
read(4, "\1\0\0\1\4+\0\0\2\3def\5gammu\6outbox\6outbo"..., 16384) = 325
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 202) = 202
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
write(4, "\222\0\0\0\3UPDATE outbox SET `SendingT"..., 150) = 150
read(4, "0\0\0\1\0\1\0\2\0\0\0(Rows matched: 1  Cha"..., 16384) = 52
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
[...] repeats for hundreds of times..
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 229) = 229
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
write(4, "\255\0\0\0\3SELECT `Text`, `Coding`, `U"..., 177) = 177
read(4, "\1\0\0\1\v/\0\0\2\3def\5gammu\6outbox\6outbo"..., 16384) = 936
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 66) = 66
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 71) = 71
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 63) = 63
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 87) = 87
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 131) = 131
write(5, "AT+CSCA?\r", 9)               = 9
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
select(6, [5], NULL, NULL, {0, 50000})  = 1 (in [5], left {0, 46166})
read(5, "AT+CSCA?\r", 65536)            = 9
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
select(6, [5], NULL, NULL, {0, 50000})  = 1 (in [5], left {0, 49778})
read(5, "\r\n+CSCA: \"+491770610000\",145\r\n\r\n"..., 65536) = 36
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 63) = 63
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 81) = 81
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 57) = 57
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 68) = 68
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 68) = 68
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 89) = 89
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 131) = 131
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 131) = 131
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 131) = 131
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 69) = 69
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 104) = 104
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 111) = 111
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 86) = 86
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 90) = 90
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 65) = 65
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 70) = 70
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 80) = 80
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 73) = 73
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 87) = 87
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 131) = 131
write(5, "AT+CBC\r", 7)                 = 7
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
select(6, [5], NULL, NULL, {0, 50000})  = 1 (in [5], left {0, 49418})
read(5, "AT+CBC\r", 65536)              = 7
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
select(6, [5], NULL, NULL, {0, 50000})  = 1 (in [5], left {0, 49905})
read(5, "\r\n+CBC: 2,0\r\n\r\nOK\r\n", 65536) = 19
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 61) = 61
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 64) = 64
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 57) = 57
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 68) = 68
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 68) = 68
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 89) = 89
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 131) = 131
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 131) = 131
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 73) = 73
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 86) = 86
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 63) = 63
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 63) = 63
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 79) = 79
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 80) = 80
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 78) = 78
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 87) = 87
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
write(3, "Wed 2015/07/08 00:05:51 gammu-sm"..., 131) = 131
write(5, "AT+CSQ\r", 7)                 = 7
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
select(6, [5], NULL, NULL, {0, 50000})  = 1 (in [5], left {0, 46575})
read(5, "AT+CSQ\r", 65536)              = 7
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
select(6, [5], NULL, NULL, {0, 50000})  = 1 (in [5], left {0, 49808})
read(5, "\r\n+CSQ: 11,99\r\n\r\nOK\r\n", 65536) = 21
```

## Config Files

`/root/.gammurc`

```
[gammu]

port = /dev/ttyUSB0
model = 
connection = at
synchronizetime = yes
logfile = /var/log/sms/gammu.log
logformat = nothing
use_locking = no
gammuloc =
```

`/etc/gammu-smsdrc`

```
# This is a sample Gammu SMSD configuration file. It's required for gammu-smsd,
# see gammu-smsdrc(5) for documentation.

# Gammu configuration, this section is like section "gammu" in "gammurc" file,
# see gammurc(5) for documentation.
[gammu]
device = /dev/ttyUSB0
connection = at

[smsd]
Service = sql
Driver = native_mysql
User = xxx
Password = xxx
PC = localhost
Database = xxx
PIN =
LogFile = /var/log/sms/gammu-smsd
debuglevel = 255
PhoneID = UMTSStick
receive = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to see SMSD log as well, but I think it's bug which has been fixed in 1.35.0, so please upgrade Gammu.

Comment: I have update to gammu 1.36.0-1, but still not working. Now it seems that gammu is not able to connect to the device at all.

Comment: Seems like there is also a hardware issue with the stick. It keeps disconnecting many times and /dev/ttyUSB* devices are getting renumbered.

Comment: One thing I just realized is that you should use use_locking = yes and define different devices for gammu and gammu-smsd. When using the same device for both services it's causing problems for gammu-smsd, so it cannot be ended. Who knows what else. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I did not realize this might be issue as well - I've just added advisory locking to Gammu, so it won't steal device itself: https://github.com/gammu/gammu/commit/069a5c107f0a044624f0869f64940b18c9fd1a91